# Will uploaded images, that are no longer referenced, be removed?

Tags: support, questions

I uploaded an image for this question: [Is it just a coincidence that the locations of three cities in North America share a unique geographical similarity to three cities in Europe?](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/64414/is-it-just-a-coincidence-that-the-locations-of-three-cities-in-north-america-sha).

I accidentally damaged the link while editing, so had to upload the image a second time.

Will the first image eventually be removed since it is no longer being referenced?

Comment: Got me stumped on that one. There might already be an answer over on meta.se.